# A game community equivalent to IMDb Pro?

Tags: business, publishing, intellectual-property

Is there one resource that tracks and lists games in development, similar to what IMDb Pro does for films in development? MobyGames is good for post-mortem, who did what, but what about a resource that gives you intel on what games are in production?

Comment: IMDB lists video games.

Comment: @Noctrine: Usually only if it's part of a non-video-game actor/artists's CV, and almost never ones in development. Example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1125798/fullcredits#cast - No artists are listed unless they have a movie credit elsewhere, and only one programmer is listed, who also has has a movie credit. No designers are listed at all.

Comment: erm... music tag?

Answer (score 5):

While I doubt you will find anything that lists games that are in production stages. (The Industry usually remains a bit more tight-lipped about such things than the film industry does)

The rest of what you are looking for is handled relatively nicely by [MobyGames](http://www.mobygames.com/)

EDIT: Almost forgot, [GiantBomb](http://www.giantbomb.com) Also has the same sort of Data.